# Make file, separate compilation failed

Tags: c, makefile

i try to do a Make file, (separate compilation), but the compiler gives me this error

here is the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'stringFunction.o', needed by 'stringsmake'.  Stop.
```

and here is my make.mak:

```
  # Dateiname: stringsmake.mak

stringsmake: stringFunction.o stringMain.o                                                  
        gcc -o stringsmake stringFunction.o stringMain.o

stringFunctions.o: stringFunctions.h stringFunctions.c                                                                           
        gcc -c stringFunctions.c

stringmain.o: stringFunctions.h Stringmain.c                                                             
        gcc -c Stringmain.c
```

Comment: `stringFunctions.c` versus `stringFunction.o`...

Comment: Also `Stringmain.c` versus `stringMain.o`.

Comment: Also `stringsmake: ...` and then `gcc -o mystring ...`? I think you need to take a step back and study more about makefiles, and targets.

Comment: i edit my question.

Comment: Note that make has pretty good implicit rules, and if you don't mind not explicitly expressing the dependency on the header files you can get away with the single line: `stringsmake: stringFunction.o stringMain.o` (Assuming `Stringmain.c` vs `stringMain.o` is a typo and you aren't actually mixing case.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of mismatches between different filenames. Both in spelling but also with upper- and lower-cases.

I suggest you learn how to use *implicit rules*, *automatic variables* and "standard" *variables* to create simpler makefiles.

Perhaps something like this:

```
# Standard flag for C source compilations
# Add option for extra warnings
CFLAGS = -Wall

# The main target
mystring: Stringmain.o stringFunctions.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

That's it really. There are implicit rules to build object files from C source files using the `CFLAGS` variable.

The automatic variable `$@` expands to the current target, and the variable `$^` expands to all the prerequisites. So `$(CC) -o $@ $^` will expand to `$(CC) -o mystring Stringmain.o stringFunctions.o`.

You can add explicit rules to list dependencies (like the header files) but omit any command. Then the implicit rules will be used for the generation of the object files.

Please take some time to study the manual of the `make` program you're using (for example [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)).

Comment: # Dateiname: stringsmake.mak
stringsmake: stringFunction.o stringMain.o
        gcc -o stringsmake stringFunction.o stringMain.o
stringFunctions.o: stringFunctions.h stringFunctions.c
        gcc -c stringFunctions.c
stringmain.o: stringFunctions.h Stringmain.c
        gcc -c Stringmain.c

Comment: i changed it see above, now is the error:                                                                                                                  make: *** No rule to make target 'stringFunction.o', needed by 'stringsmake'.  Stop.

Comment: @adersat `stringFunction.o` versus `stringFunctions.o`...

Comment: i changed it but the error is already there

Comment: @adersat And please don't "fix" your question in update to answers. That makes the question worthless as the problem you ask about doesn't exist.

Comment: This is the right approach.  Note that the line `$(CC) -o $@ $^` can be omitted.  (As can the CFFLAGS assignment (but keeping it is a good idea), making this a one-line Makefile).

Answer (score 0):

The below `Makefile` should do the job. But change `stringFunctions.c` to `stringFunction.c` and `Stringmain.c` to `stringMain.c`.

```
BASE = stringsmake
CXX = gcc
LIBFLAGS=-lm

main: $(BASE)

%.o: %.cc
      $(CXX) -c -o$@ $<

$(BASE): stringFunctions.o stringMain.o
      $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBFLAGS)

stringFunctions.o: stringFunctions.h
stringMain.o: stringFunctions.h
```

Comment: The `-o` option needs an argument, which you don't pass.

Comment: Ooh, yes. Thanks.

Comment: @adersat try this one now.